# How to get key from a mapped object

Tags: reactjs

I'm mapping some objects with the code below

```
<div className='groups'>
      {
                    groups.map(({id,...otherGroupProps}) => (
                        <GroupItem key={id}{...otherGroupProps}/>
                    ))
                }
      </div>
```

But in the GroupItem component I can't access the id, i try the following code:

```
const GroupItem = ({id,title}) => (
    <Link
      className='group-item'
      to={`/groups/${id}`}
    >
      <div className='content'>
      <h1 className='title'>{title}</h1>
      </div>
    </Link>
  );
```

The title arrvies alright, but the id comes ad undefined, can you tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: you're not passing it...

Comment: since you're destructing, if you want to pass the id you would have to join it again or pass as id separately

Comment: Hello @Noriller , could you please show me how?

Answer (score 0):

basically you want something like:

```js
<GroupItem key={id} id={id} title={otherGroupProps.title}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

as long as it's not it the otherGroupProps you need to add it by yourself.

```
<GroupItem key={id} id={id} title={otherGroupProps.title}/>
```

another point that should be consider while mapping is that id that come from the index is good for static stuff while a list that can be change is better to you a identifier inside the object you pass